# Solving the functional equation $f(x^2+f(y))=(f(x))^2+y$

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations

Find all $ f : R\rightarrow R $ such that $f(x^2+f(y))=(f(x))^2+y, \forall\text{ x,y}\in R$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of equation is called [*functional equations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) and are very well known to be posted in Olympiads of mathematics, solving them does not require heavy prerequisites it requires only [technical methods](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=339&lmm=0).

> **Solution** The given equation has only one solutions $f=Id_\Bbb R$.

In order to solve your equation, assume that $f$ is a function such that:
$$\begin{align} \forall x,y\in \Bbb R^2&& f(x^2+f(y))=y +f(x)^2 \tag 1\end{align}$$
From $(1)$ we have $f$ is onto hence we can find an element $a$ such that $f(a)=0$, it follows from $(1)$ that $y=f(a^2+f(y))=f((-a)^2+f(y))=y+f(-a)^2$ hence $f(-a)=0$ now by taking $x=0, y=\mp a$ in $(1)$ we have $f(0)=\mp a+f(0)^2$ this possible only if $a=0$ and hence $f(0)=0$.

Now if we take $x=0$ in $(1)$ we have:
$$\begin{align} \forall x,y\in \Bbb R^2&& f\left(f\left(y\right)\right)=y+f(0)^2=y\tag2\end{align}$$

and we use $(2)$ to expand $(1)$  when $y$ is replaced by $f(y)$ so that:
$$\begin{align} \forall x,y\in \Bbb R^2&&  f\left(x^2+y\right)=f(y)+f(x)^2\tag{3}\end{align}$$
and from $(1)$ again with $y=0$ we have $$f(x^2)=(f(x))^2 \tag 4$$  now given $t$ positive $t=x^2$ in $(3)$ gives :
$$f(t+y)=f(t)+f(y)\tag 5$$
but this equation can be extended to negative reals $t$ using $(4)$ ( To made things clear from $4$ we have $(f(t)^2)=f(-t)^2=f(t^2)$ ad the injectivity from $(2)$ gives us that $f(-t)=-f(t)$)

Return to $(5)$ the functions solutions verify for $f(x)=f(1)x$ for $x\in \Bbb Q$, the relation $(3)$ justifies that $f(x)$ increases monotonously so that $f(x)=f(1)x$ for every real $x\in \mathbb R$. using $(4)$ we have $f(1)\geq 0$ and from $2$ we have $f(1)^2=1$ hence $f(1)=1$.

> **Exercise :** For a given natural number $k > 2$, find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f[x^k + f(y)] = y +[f(x)]^k$.

Comment: How can negative identity be a solution when $f$ is nondecreasing per $(3)$?

Comment: Strictly increasing (or just injectiveness), $f(0)=0$ and $(4)$ tells you that $f(1)=f(1)^2\Rightarrow (f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1)\Rightarrow f(1)=1$. It's the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing and $f(0)=0$ that implies $f(1)>0$ but I'm unsure how you used $(4)$ to show that $f(1)>0$. Be more specific. Then it's unclear how $(2)$ implies $f(1)^2=1$, since all it implies is $f(f(1))=1$. Why does $f(1)^2=f(f(1))$?

Comment: we have $f(x)=f(1)x$ so $f(f(1))=f(1)^2=1$ it's not really complicated, $f(1)$ is positive because $f(1)x^2=f(x)^2$ from $4$

Comment: we have from $4$ for every $x$ : $f(x^2)=f(1)x^2=f(x)^2$ so $f(1)$ is positive and I will change the inequality to $f(1)\geq 0$ but this does not matter